# Why checkbox is not maintaining it's value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, webforms

I came across an interesting problem.

I have a checkbox inside a gridview (which is inside the MODAL). Upon CLosingModal event i am fetching Checkbox but it shows FALSE, even though i check True.

Why ?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Conveyed ?">
  <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBoxIsConveyed" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("IsConveyed")) %>' />
         </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

.cs

```
protected void btnCloseModal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mdlLastHearingDates.Hide();

        UpdateIsConveyed();

    }

public void UpdateIsConveyed() 
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow r in grdViewLastHearingDates.Rows)
        {
            int CaseHearingID = Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[0].Text);
            CheckBox chkBox = r.FindControl("chkBoxIsConveyed") as CheckBox;

            MngCaseHearings.UpdateCasesIsConveyed(CaseHearingID, chkBox.Checked);
        }
    }
```

I debugged and it calls the functions.

Comment: Try reverse of what you have done. First update your data then hide the modal.

Comment: ok wait sir, i ma trying

Comment: sorry sir, but no luck :/

Comment: Try Bind instead of eval. For 2 way databinding you'll need to use Bind.

Comment: @NitinAlapati not working

Comment: Any chance that you disabled viewState for the page or control?

Comment: Are you binding the grid during the postback also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set AutoPostBack value to true, where I believe it does not fire the event to update the model when you checked the checkbox. For more information, you may refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.autopostback(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: no it;s not true, it does fire the event and read my question carefully

Comment: I'm suppose the event you meant is UpdateIsConveyed()? But it wasn't what I tried to said, what I meant was the checkbox checked event. Okay, let me explain further. You binded the value to the UI (client side scripting), and you want to get the updated value from code-behind (server side scripting), then you will need to post the value back to the server when you perform checked checkbox action, Therefore, you will need to add AutoPostBack property to your checkbox and set it to true.